# Typescript private and protected members exposed to angular 1.x view

Tags: angularjs, typescript

It seems like when combining TS and angular, everything i have on a controller is exposed to the view. In my case, `myPrivate` will appear on `$ctrl`.

```
class MyController extends BaseController implements SomeInterface {
    private myPrivate: string = 'myPrivateString';
}
```

Is there any workaround around this issue?

Comment: Have you tried a parameterized constructor to initialize your private member??

Comment: I'd like not to only discriminate but also prevent the actual usage.

Comment: That's actually pretty solid argument IMO. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious why when you look at the generated javascript.

```js
var MyController = (function (_super) {
    __extends(MyController, _super);
    function MyController() {
        _super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.myPrivate = 'myPrivateString';
    }
    return MyController;
}(BaseController));
```

Your private property ends up as any other property on your controller.

You can see the full transpilation [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20MyController%20extends%20BaseController%20implements%20SomeInterface%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20myPrivate%3A%20string%20%3D%20'myPrivateString'%3B%0D%0A%7D).

A solution would be to have a parameterized base controller able to set something like a view model for the view to use, instead of the regular $ctrl.

It would look something like this:

```js
class BaseController<T> {

    protected scope;
    protected viewModel: T;

    constructor(scope: any, modelType: { new (): T; }) {
        this.scope = scope;

        this.viewModel = new modelType();

        this.scope["viewModel"] = this.viewModel;
    }
}

class MyParticularViewModel {
    public somethingForTheView: string;
}

class MyController extends BaseController<MyParticularViewModel> implements SomeInterface {
    private myPrivate: string = 'myPrivateString';

    constructor(scope) {
        super(scope, MyParticularViewModel);
    }
}
```

In the view you can then use the **viewModel** property to access the needed properties.

I have used this in a project in practice and it worked out pretty well. You can see a starter template that I used [here](https://github.com/Justin-Credible/Ionic-TypeScript-Starter/blob/master/src/Framework/BaseController.ts) for more info.

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply and giving a good idea, but i thought about something like this and was hoping maybe there's something less patchy.

Comment: I don't see how, if you are to inject your controller directly into the view then all it's properties will be available to the view to use. The private keyword is only taken into account at compilation time by tsc, it's available at runtime for anyone to use.

Comment: also I wouldn't say it's patchy.. it allows you to have a proper contract between the controller and your views (in case you ever want to reuse the controllers).